# Enabling restricted access to limited columns in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2010

In my excel worksheet there is a table containing 5 columns say Column A- Column E. I want to do apply following restrictions to it - 
1. User should not be able to edit one column i.e. Column A and the rest of the columns he can input the data.
2. User should not be able to delete or insert new row but should be able to enter the data.
3. For a particular row, Column B and Column E are mandatory and the user should be thrown an error if the excel is saved or before moving to the next entry.

Could someone help me on what are the best ways to go about enabling such restrictions? Online help is not very helpful currently as protect worksheet is the only thing that I am getting redirected to which is pretty confusing and its a all or none approach.

Comment: These are three separate and unrelated questions. Only the third question is not obviously off-topic here at Stack Overflow. Consider asking at SuperUser instead (superuser.com).

Comment: If you right click on a cell (or set of cells), the last tab is "Protection". You can de-select ````locked````, and when you protect the worksheet, the unlocked cells will not be affected by the protection. For the row values to be enforced (so can't left blank), I'd suggest using VBA, like this: ````If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, 3).Value) Then
MsgBox "This can not be empty.", vbInformation````

Comment: Do you want to allow users to be able to extend your table (i.e. add new rows to the bottom)?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Alex - I was able to solve restriction 1 by unlocking the sheets to edit and protecting others. However I don't understand the VB code that you have listed and how it works. The requirement is throughout the table, for any given row, while inputting the data i.e. say Column A is filled, then Column B and E should be filled. Can this be done?   Mark - No, users should not be able to add new rows.